# Google authentication and jwt bearer

Tags: asp.net-core, web, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have a .Net Core Api with jwt bearer authentication. I want the end user to be able to connect normally(with email and password) or with a google account.
As of now when the user logs in (with e-mail and pass) he receives a token.

My **startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("AFhu9aVrbdUN3G4Vv87jWA7gCSuJG8c8D7cp7XrUMayEtcryWpGJzDQMnV7")),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
                
            });
```

I've tried following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I've added this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

            options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
        });
```

I don't know how to continue from here on

Comment: What do you mean "you can't just add this code in startup.cs"? What goes wrong?

Comment: Sorry, i ve updated my question. Thank you for taking your time to read it :)

Comment: Since you are sign in by Google, why do you also need jwt bearer authentication?

Comment: It would be great for me if the user could log in with google, but at the same time have the possibility of signing in with just email and password if he chooses to.

Comment: The Google external login in the document is based on asp.net core Identity. If you don't use it, you can follow this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nQf76HF20A&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: If you can tell us what frontend system are you using, I could try to write an answer; if it's still relevant. :) Since for OICD login you'll have to open Google's sign in page so the user can select their account and accept the shared information scopes, which requires some form of frontend (unless my admittedly poor knowledge about OICD is even poorer than I thought).

Comment: Hi, yes, i still haven t figured it out yet:)    I am using xamarin forms